# query not displaying the expected output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and records are as below

```
------------------------------------------------
id |m_id  | primary | secondary  | Duration
------------------------------------------------
1  |  1   | 100     | 80         | 12m
------------------------------------------------
2  |  1   | 50      | 40         | 6m
------------------------------------------------
3  |  2   | 300     | 150        | 12m
------------------------------------------------
4  |  2   | 150     | 70         | 6m
------------------------------------------------
5  |  3   | 500     | 300         | 12m
------------------------------------------------
6  |  3   | 300      | 200         | 6m
```

I need an output like this. Notice here I am displaying the data month wise.

```
--------------------------------------------
id  |m_id | primary        | secondary    
    |     | 12m |6m        |12m   |6m        
--------------------------------------------
1   |1    |100  |50        | 80  |40  
--------------------------------------------
2   |2    |300  |150       | 150  |70 
--------------------------------------------
3   |3    |500  |300       | 300  |200
```

but I am getting the output like( I haven't added amount)

```
   --------------------------------------------
id  |m_id | primary        | secondary    
    |     | 12m |6m        |12m   |6m        
--------------------------------------------
1   |1    |
--------------------------------------------
1   |1    |
--------------------------------------------
2   |1    |  
--------------------------------------------
3   |2    | 
--------------------------------------------
3   |2    |  
--------------------------------------------
4   |2    |
```

I tried query

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_activityFees2` as `t1`
JOIN `tbl_activityFees2` as `t2` ON `t2`.`m_id`=`t1`.`m_id`
JOIN `activity_name` ON `activity_name`.`m_id`=`t1`.`m_id`
WHERE `t1`.`is_feesActive` = 1
AND `t2`.`is_feesActive` = 1
AND `t1`.`Duration` = '12m'
OR `t2`.`Duration` = '6m'
```

Would you help me out on this issue?

Comment: `WHERE t1.is_feesActive = 1
AND t2.is_feesActive = 1
AND t1.Duration = '12m'
OR t2.Duration = '6m'` looks wrong i advice you to read about [operator precedences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: To chose what to display, you have to work on the select part.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Thanks for the information also I forgot the add the is_feesActive in the table. Can you help me out what's wrong in it? I have to use AND operator instated of OR. right?

Answer (score 1):

You can group up with max logic followed by join with the main table as follows

```
   select `t1`.id
          ,grouped_data.*
     from(
    SELECT `t1`.m_id
           ,max(case when `t1`.duration='12m' then primary end) as primary_12m
           ,max(case when `t1`.duration='6m' then primary end)  as primary_6m   
           ,max(case when `t1`.duration='12m' then secondary end) as secondary_12m
           ,max(case when `t1`.duration='6m' then secondary end)  as secondary_6m          
      FROM `tbl_activityFees2` as `t1`
     WHERE `t1`.`is_feesActive` = 1
    GROUP BY `t1`.m_id
          ) grouped_data
    JOIN `tbl_activityFees2` as `t1`      
      on t1.m_id=grouped_data.m_id
```

Comment: Note that this is a MySQL 8.0+ only query.

Comment: Thanks for that i have modified and removed the "with" clause

Comment: @George, Can you help me out how to use your code? It's hard to understand for me

Comment: The grouped_data is the code which does the aggregation based on the m_id, ie for  every unique m_id we extract the possible 12m and 6m values for the primary and secondary columns. After that i just join with the main table tbl_activityfees2 to extract the id as well

Comment: There is an error ,      on t1.m_id=t2.m_id.  I thing t2 is not defined

Comment: I have updated, it should have read grouped_data.m_id.my apologies

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, Yes, I am trying to understand your answer, I am just a learner. After some time I have to convert your query to CodeIgniter

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, I am not getting the expected output. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue and what is the result you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a full outer join. Since full outer joins are not supported in MySQL, you'll need to simulate them by `UNION`ing to `OUTER JOIN`s, as in:

```
select
  coalesce(t1.m_id, 2.m_id) as m_id,
  t2.primary as primary_12m,
  t1.primary as primary_6m,
  t2.secondary as secondary_12m,
  t1.secondary as secondary_6m
from tbl_activityFees2 t1
left join tbl_activityFees2 t2 
  on t1.m_id = t2.m_id
 and t1.duration = '6m'
 and t2.duration = '12m'
 and t1.is_feesActive = 1
 and t2.is_feesActive = 1
union
select
  coalesce(t1.m_id, 2.m_id) as m_id,
  t2.primary as primary_12m,
  t1.primary as primary_6m,
  t2.secondary as secondary_12m,
  t1.secondary as secondary_6m
from tbl_activityFees2 t2
left join tbl_activityFees2 t1
  on t1.m_id = t2.m_id
 and t1.duration = '6m'
 and t2.duration = '12m'
 and t1.is_feesActive = 1
 and t2.is_feesActive = 1
```

Comment: MySQL does not support `full outer join`

Comment: Edited. the full outer join is now simulated by two union-ed outer joins.

Comment: shouldn't you simulate `full outer join` with a LEFT JOIN and a RIGHT JOIN?

Comment: @RaymondNijland left and right join is the same, just the tables are in a different order.

Comment: Yeah, that's also a possibility, I just switched the table order (in this case is the same table on both sides).

Comment: "left and right join is the same, just the tables are in a different order." Yes offcource i know @Shadow i mean the second LEFT JOIN in his query should be RIGHT JOIN because he didn't switched the table order. And i also believe the second (RIGHT/LEFT) JOIN should include a IS NULL filter Editted: never mind you used `union` which removes duplicates so the a IS NULL filter is not needed.